# How to configure Spring Social to generate redirect HTTPS URLs?

Tags: spring-social

My entire website is under HTTPS. Any HTTP URL will be redirected to corresponding HTTPS link.

When I set up redirect URLs in Google and Facebook, only HTTP URLs match. How can I configure Spring Social to let Facebook or Google match redirect HTTPS URLs?

Comment: I was facing similar issue . But it was due to SSL offloading.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no simple solution yet. There are tickets open here: [URIBuilder does not respect x-forwarded headers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/issues/224) and here [Redirect URL generation behind proxy server](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SOCIAL-447)
The later one has a brief description which classes to override as workaround.